# Having issues downloading pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

I tried pip install --upgradepywinauto in powershell and it seemed to work correctly. But when I run the code in Jupyter Notebook I got a Module Error.

I have Python 3.8 downloaded. I uninstalled and reinstalled Python and still get this error. Any suggestions?

The code I'm running in jupyter notebook is below:

```
import pywinauto.mouse as mouse
import pywinauto.keyboard as keyboard
```

Comment: can you share your error log ?

Comment: Please check you have only one Python installation. Or use full path to `pip.exe` for proper Python installation. Try `import sys; print(sys.executable)` in Jupyter notebook to see which Python is used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this related but may u try with python 3.6? because

```
import pywinauto.mouse as mouse 
import pywinauto.keyboard as keyboard
```

seems fine for me :D

Comment: So I had Python 3.8 on the computer I was running it on. It works with 3.7.4, which is what I used to develop the code. It looks like 3.7.4 is the highest it works on. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you named your script `pywinauto.py`, right? This is wrong way to re-define package name. Name the script properly.